# How to pass parameter ajax contentType: "html"

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I'm trying this but "myvariable" is passing null. What am I doing wrong?

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/MyController/MyAction",
    data: JSON.stringify({
        products: myvariable
    }),
    contentType: "html"
}).done(function(a) {
    if (null != a) $(".item-box").html(a);
}).fail(function(a) {
    if (0 != a.status) alert(a.status + " " + a.statusText);
});
```

Comment: Can we see where you assign the value of `myvariable` ?

Comment: @MasterDJon I assigned from another ajax call. It's a object.

Comment: Did you verify, if at this point (before ajax call), `myvariable` isn't already null ?

Comment: Yes I checked but it is not null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Ensure what is sent to server by using the network tab of developers tools in Chrome or you're favorite browser. If what is sent is how you expect to receive it in server continue to #2 otherwise do the answer of @Rikin.
2. On the server side, follow your code from the beginning of the page call.

Comment: Thank you. Yes I don't pass the first step.

Answer (score 0):

As per jquery documentation:
The processing might be undesirable if you wish to send an XML object to the server; in this case, change the contentType option from `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` to a more appropriate MIME type.

So may be you can try `contentType: "text/html"` OR you may want to try `processData: false`